# What is a streak of ten?

Tags: achievements, plants-vs-zombies

The Plants vs. Zombies achievement [Better Off Dead](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Better_Off_Dead) requires that you

> Get to a streak of 10 in I, Zombie Endless.

What does that mean?

I've searched & searched and can find nothing specific. I watched a couple of Youtube videos, and it was completely unclear as to what created a 'streak'.

Answer (score 6):

[I, Zombie Endless](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/I,_Zombie_Endless) is a puzzle mode version of I, Zombie where any sun you have at the end of a level (eating all five brains) carries over to help you in the next level.

To get the achievement, you must clear ten levels in a row, without losing all your sun (and thus not being able to deploy any more zombies).